# combine find and grep into a single command

Tags: bash, shell

How to combine below two into one line without changing the first one?

```
 # find / -name sshd_config -print
 # grep -I <sshd_config path>  permitrootlogin
```

I came up with the following, but don't know whether I gives correct result in different cases

```
cat `find / -name sshd_config -print` |grep permitrootlogin
```

Comment: Combine *how*, exactly? What's your goal?

Comment: In your first command, `permitrootlogin` is the name of a file to search, and `<sshd_config path>` is what you're searching for. In the second command, `permitrootlogin` is the string to search. Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

Don't do `cat $(...)` [`$()` is the modern replacement for backticks] -- that doesn't work reliably if your filenames contain special characters (spaces, wildcards, etc).

Instead, tell `find` to invoke `cat` for you, with as many filenames passed to each `cat` invocation as possible:

```
find / -name sshd_config -exec cat -- '{}' + | grep permitrootlogin
```

...or, even better, ignore `cat` altogether and just pass the filenames to `grep` literally:

```
find / -name sshd_config -exec grep -h -e permitrootlogin -- /dev/null '{}' +
```

Replace the `-h` with `-H` if you want filenames to be shown.

Comment: What does the `+` at the end do?

Comment: @SeanBright, the `+` tells `-exec` to pass more than one filename on each invocation, compared to `';'`, which would pass one each.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - nice.  hadn't see that before.  thanks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Also worth mentioning the `-print0 | xargs -0r` approach.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, ...would it be? If we were parallelizing, with `xargs -P`, I'd understand it, but there's not much value added over baseline `find -exec {} +` otherwise. Also, `find -exec {} +` is part of the POSIX standard (as of 2006), whereas `xargs -0` is not.

Comment: Also, maybe you should use `grep -H` not `-h`, but it's not at all clear which the OP wants.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, well, the original `cat` wouldn't have included filenames, so `-H` is maintaining the stock behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, `-H` is not identical to the default behaviour in the case there is only one file passed to `grep`.  `xargs` is worth mentioning simply because it's a valid approach which many people don't know about and it comes in handy in other situations, e.g. where `find(1)` is not the feeder to `grep`.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, ahh! I knew there was a second reason I was including `/dev/null` explicitly in an earlier version of this answer, but couldn't think of what it was. Added it back now, removing that corner case.

Comment: @SeanBright +1 for the sheer cheek of asking that whilst having 48k rep ;-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Also, the perfect answer would point out that `find /` is a really bad idea ...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why is `/dev/null` still there?  It's only necessary if neither `-h` nor `-H` are present.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, ...because it's easier to showcase something that behaves consistently when modified a bit than to explain changes that would need to be added if an option were removed. In short, I'd rather folks copying/pasting and changing my code [since anything given on StackOverflow can be _expected_ to be modified to fit] eat a little bit of (constant-time) inefficiency than that they get inconsistent results.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, ...that said, I'm +1'ing your comment, since it's a worthwhile thing for folks reading this to be aware of.

Comment: (Aside: `{}` doesn't need to be quoted in bash, but _does_ need to be quoted in zsh; I'm quoting it here for maximum compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like that:

```
find / -name "somefilename" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "something"
```

The 'xargs' keyword will transform the stdout into arguments that can be read by grep.

Comment: This is buggy with filenames that `xargs` can't handle correctly -- not just names with literal newlines, but also names with literal quotes. (That's why `find -print0` and `xargs -0` is necessary for `xargs` to be safely used with arbitrary names).

Comment: You are right that -print0 and xargs -0 should be uses together in this case, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is use the output of `find / -name sshd_config -print` (which should be the path of the `sshd_config` file) and use it as the second argument to `grep` (so that that the `sshd_config` file gets parsed for your search string).

There are several ways to achieve this.

Commands in back-quotes (`` ` ``) are replaced by their output. So

```
grep permitrootlogin `find / -name sshd_config -print`
```

will be replaced by

```
grep permitrootlogin /path/to/the/sshd_config
```

which will search `/path/to/the/sshd_config` for `permitrootlogin`.

The same happens with

```
grep permitrootlogin $(find / -name sshd_config -print)
```

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549651/674064) already mentions, this syntax has some advantages over the back-ticks. Namely, it can be nested.

However, this still runs into a problem when the path where the file is found contains spaces. As both backticks and `$(...)` just perform text substitution, such a patch would be passed as several arguments to `grep`, each probably being an invalid path. (`/path/to the/sshd_config` would become `/path/to` and `the/sshd_config`.)

Rather than working around this with fancy quoting and escaping strategies, remember that UNIX commands were already designed for being used in combination, usually by pipes. Indeed `find` has a `-print0` action which will separate paths of found files by `\0`, so that they can be distinguished from paths containing whitespace. Alas, `grep` can't process a zero-delimited list of files and still wants the files to search as invocation arguments, not on `stdin`.

This is where `xargs` comes into play. It applies stuff it gets on `stdin` as arguments to other commands. And with its `-0` option, it interprets `stdin` as a zero-delimited list instead of treating whitespace as delimiters.

So

```
find / -name sshd_config -print0 | xargs -0 grep permitrootlogin
```

should have you covered.

Answer (score -1):

| is a pipeline, which means, that the standard output of `cat`find / -name sshd_config -print`` will go to standard intput of `grep permitrootlogin`, so you just have to be sure what's the output of the first command

Comment: Buggy -- doesn't correctly handle filenames with spaces. Also, check your formatting.